# Direct Sum involving integration

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> Let $U$ be the subspace of polynomials $P$ defined as follows
>   $$U=\left\{p(x)\in P ~ \text{so that } \int _0^1 p\left(x\right)dx=\int _0^1xp\left(x\right)dx=0\right\}.$$ 
>   Is the following statement true or false?
>   $$P=P_1⊕U.$$
>   Where $P_1$ is the set of all polynomials with degree at most $1$.

Since $P$ has an infinite dimension and $P_1$ has dimension of $2$, the only way that this statement could potentially be true would have been if $U$ also had an infinite dimension. After doing a general integration of an infinitely long polynomial with coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, and so on, along with decreasing powers of $x$ starting from $n$, I got that for both integrals to equal $0$, all coefficients would have to be $0$. This led me to think the dimension of $U$ was $0$.

And since infinity does not equal $2+0$, I thought that this statement was false.

This is my work:

So I let $p\left(x\right)=ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\dots+kx^0$

Therefore, 
$$\int _0^1\:ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\dots+kx^0=\int _0^1\:x\left(ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\dots+kx^0\right)=0$$
This led to:
$$\frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{bx^n}{n}+\dots+kx=\frac{ax^{n+2}}{n+2}+\frac{bx^{n+1}}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{kx^2}{2}=0$$
Which led to:
$$\frac{a\left(1\right)^{n+1}}{1+1}+\frac{b\left(1\right)^n}{n}+\dots+k=\frac{a\left(1\right)^{n+2}}{n+2}+\frac{b\left(1\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{k\left(1\right)^2}{2}=0$$

This led to believe that all coefficients had to be $0$ as that's the only way to get $0$ as the answer. But I am not sure whether I have done the integration correctly.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. Any polynomial $p$ can be written in a unique way as the sum of a polynomial of degree at most one and a polynomial in $U$.

Let $p\in P$ with 
$\int _0^1p(x)dx=A$ and $\int _0^1xp(x)dx=B$.
Then there is $q\in P_1$ such that $p-q\in U$ iff
$$\begin{cases}\int _0^1(p(x)-ax-b)dx=0\\
\int _0^1x(p(x)-ax-b)dx=0\end{cases}$$
where $q(x)=a+bx$. After integrating, we obtain
$$\begin{cases}\frac{a}{2}+b=A\\
\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}=B\end{cases}$$
Given $A$ and $B$, this linear system has a unique solution:
$$(a,b)=(-6A+12B,4A-6B).$$
P.S. $U$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space: we can easily verify that for all $n\geq 2$
$$q_n(x)=x^n-\frac{6nx-2(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\in U.$$
In fact
$$\int_0^1 q_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{3n-2(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=0$$
and 
$$\int_0^1 xq_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{2n-(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I just ask how you determined that $U$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space (i.e. how did you determine a general formula for polynomials in $U$)? I was trying to determine its dimension with the working I have shown but I guess I did it wrong. And if so, for the statement to be true, would it not have to be the case that the intersection between $P1$ and $U$ is only the zero vector? If, so, could you be so kind to tell how that is the case? Thank you again!

Comment: See my P.S.. Moreover the intersection of $P_1$ and $U$ is just the polynomial zero because the system with $A=B=0$, yields the solution $a=b=0$.